# Static IP for Oracle VM instance and rDNS set up in OCI

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How can we get static IPs for a OCI VM instance? Also, how can I configure reverse DNS for this Oracle-owned IP address?

I have visited https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/DNS/Tasks/reversedns.htm but this seems to create a DNS zone and record for normal forward zones. How will Oracle update the reverse DNS zones in their zone files?

Comment: The first question ("How can we get static IPs for a OCI VM instance?") is answered by the content at https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingpublicIPs.htm about reserved addresses (which have a lifecycle independent of any VNIC private address with which they are temporarily associated).

Answer (score 4):

The Public IP address assigned to the VM stays with it all through the life-cycle of the Instance until it is terminated. So one way, it is already static/permanent. The other option is to use Reserved IP addresses.

Could you check this link for rDNS question? Looks like it is very similar if not same.

https://cloudcustomerconnect.oracle.com/posts/21ce8bcdef